# MSSQL Declare Example

Tags: sql, sql-server

The script gives an output like the one below, but I output it, but normally it only needs to give 3 outputs.What can I do ?

```
declare @id as int;
declare @in as varchar(max);
declare @a as int;
set @id=1;

while (@id <= 54) 
Begin print @in
  --select @in (select id from TableExample where EXISTS (select * from TableExample where Schedule ='W1') );
  select DISTINCT @in =  IndexName 
  from TableExample 
  where id = @id 
  and CategoryDescription = 'WEEKLY';
  set @id +=1;
end;
```

**Output:**

```
IX_AddonProduct_Id
IX_AddonProduct_Id
IX_AddonProduct_Id
IX_AddonProduct_Id
IX_AddonProduct_Id
IX_AddonProduct_Id
IX_AddonProduct_Id
IX_RegistryNumber
IX_RegistryNumber
IX_RegistryNumber
IX_RegistryNumber
IX_RegistryNumber
IX_RegistryNumber
IX_RegistryNumber
IX_RegistryNumber
IX_RegistryNumber
IX_Pricing_Id
IX_Pricing_Id
IX_Pricing_Id
IX_Pricing_Id
IX_Pricing_Id
IX_Pricing_Id
IX_Pricing_Id
IX_Pricing_Id
```

If I set the value of 54 to 3 it shows like this:

```
IX_AddonProduct_Id
IX_AddonProduct_Id
```

Anyone have any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: What's the point of this query? SQL is a set-based language. You could write just `SELECT DISTINCT from TableExample  where id between 1 and 3 and CategoryDescription = 'WEEKLY'`. You'd still get only 2 records if there's no record with one of those ID numbers

Comment: Is it wrong to assume that `print` is only useful for debugging t-sql?

Comment: @LukStorms I would say most of the time it's debugging but not always - eg I use print output which is captured in SQL Agent job execution logs.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason for looping. You can select top 3 rows with the query

```
  select top(3) IndexName 
  from TableExample 
  where id <= 54
  and CategoryDescription = 'WEEKLY'
  order by id ;
```